# Python - Name format_string is not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, nameerror

I'm trying to create a class tree from which I can create various files and insert a list of values.I have only included code for the Delimited file. Whilst running the below code,I get the message that appears in the title, please assist.Thanks

```
from datetime import datetime as Dt
from abc import abstractmethod,ABCMeta

class FileWriter(metaclass=ABCMeta):     

    def __init__(self,FileName):
        self.FileName = FileName

    @staticmethod
    def return_time():
        return Dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    @abstractmethod
    def write(self):
        return


    def format_string(self,Values,Seperator,CSV = False):
        self.Values = Seperator.join((Values))
        if CSV == True:self.Values = Seperator.join((Values))
        return self.Values

    def write_lines(self,Values,Seperator = ","):

        print(self.Values)
        File = open(self.FileName,'w')
        File.write(self.Values + '\n')
        File.close()

class DelimitedFile(FileWriter):

    def __init__(self, FileName):
        return super().__init__(FileName)

    def format_string(self, Values, Seperator):
        self.Values = Values
        self.Seperator = Seperator
        for i in range(len(self.Values)):
            if "," in self.Values[i]:self.Values[i] = ('"' + self.Values[i] + '"')
        self.Seperator = Seperator
        return super().format_string(Values, Seperator) + ','

    def write(self,Values,Seperator=',',CSV = False):
        self.Values = str(Values)
        self.Seperator = Seperator
        self.Values = format_string(self.Values,self.Seperator)
        super().write_lines(self.Values,Seperator=',')

NewInst = DelimitedFile('Test.txt')
print(NewInst.return_time())
Values = ['s','str','trtyh','yutyuty','u7u7u7u7','e5ryru,tut','u7u7tussth','y5syyjuyju']
NewInst.write(Values)
Value = (NewInst.format_string(Values,','))
```

Comment: `self.Values = format_string(self.Values,self.Seperator)` should be `self.Values = self.format_string(self.Values,self.Seperator)`. `format_string` isn't defined in the global scope, it's in the class. Reference it through `self`.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Thank you so much! what a dope I am. Merry Christmas